# How to use setblock command for placing stone button on the left side of the command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I tried to use the command `setblock ~1 ~ ~ stone_button` but then it places a button on air.

I'm running Minecraft 14w11b snapshot from the 1.8 snapshots.

Does someone know how to fix this?

Pictures below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to also set the datavalue of the button, which corresponds to which face of the cube it attaches to.  Unfortunately, I don't know what value will work for you off hand.

Comment: Just shift-click while placing the button on the command block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the `Datavalue` of the button too, as this tells the button which direction to face. Luckily in the newest snapshots it is really easy to determine the correct datavalue by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd>, and then looking at the button you want to place.
[image: The datavalue of the button]
At the top right corner it says: `Block: minecraft:stone_button/1` which you want to place. So the full command would be:

```
setblock ~1 ~ ~ minecraft:stone_button 1
```

Comment: What is this photo editor you are using?

Comment: I think I used [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) for this one, but I am pretty sure you can do that with every major image editing program. Just select the area you want to keep, invert the selection, and reduce the brightness on the remaining area.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the command to:

```
setblock ~1 ~ ~ stone_button 1
```

The datavalue is required to change which direction the button is facing, and thus what surface it is on:

1 = East,
2 = West,
3 = South,
4 = North,
5 = Up

You can also add 8 to any of those to turn it into a pressed button in the same direction.

Answer (score -1):

> setblock ~1 ~ ~ stone_button

In this case, the number represents a direction, relative to the command block.

- **0** = DOWN
- **1** = EAST
- **2** = WEST
- **3** = SOUTH
- **4** = NORTH
- **5** = UP.